# JavaScript variable is losing value after parsing XML in Google Chrome only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running into a very strange problem.  I am using jQuery's $.get to retrieve XML from a URL. Once I have the XML, I parse the `id`, `title`, and `content` attributes. Then, I add each into an object.

For some reason, in Google Chrome only (I have no problems in IE or Firefox), the variable holding content is empty before I insert it into the object. But the variable has the correct value right after I parse the value and assign it to the variable. Here is my code, please see the comments.

```
var myarray = new Array();

$.get( "https://www.my-url.com", function( data ) {
    $(data).find('entry').each(function(){

        var id, title, content;

        $(this).find("id").each(function(){
            var id = $(this).text();
        });

        $(this).find("title").each(function(){
            title = $(this).text();
        });

        $(this).find("content").each(function(){
            content = $(this).text();
            console.log(content); // value of content is correct
        });

        console.log(content);   // value of content is empty

        var o=new myobject(id,title,content);
        myarray.push(o);

    });

});
```

What's going on?

Comment: as a side not there is no need to use `.each()`, `var id = $(this).find("id").text(),
    title = $(this).find("title").text(),
    content = $(this).find("content").text();` will do

Comment: can you share the received data

Comment: Could be the last loop iteration is setting it to empty and you just aren't seeing it because it's, well, empty. Try labelling the log, eg (in the loop) `console.log('In loop content: ', content)`

Comment: Thanks Arun P Johny, I took your sugestion and that actually fixed the problem! Please turn your comment into an answer and I will mark it as solved. Thanks again!

Comment: @littleK sure will do

Comment: @littleK but again don't know what actually caused the problem... can you share the retrieved `data` so that we can have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use an each() loop in the given scenario.

Use

```
var $this = $(this),//cached jQuery object
    id = $this.find("id").text(),
    title = $this.find("title").text(),
    content = $this.find("content").text();
```